# Angular reactive forms returning ERROR TypeError: "_co.blogTitle is undefined"

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a reactive form in Angular, but when loading the page on browser it is returning two errors **ERROR TypeError: "_co.createBlogForm.form is undefined"** and **ERROR TypeError: "_co.blogTitle is undefined"** on the console. Inside the component I've declared all the variables with formControlName and also binded FormGroup with the form name. Please have a look at my code below:

html file:

```
<div class="blog-form">
    <form [formGroup]="createBlogForm" (ngSubmit)="createBlog()">
      <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label>Blog Title</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="blogTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter blog Title"
          required>
      </div>
       <div [hidden]="blogTitle.valid || blogTitle.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
       Blog Title is required 
      </div> 

      <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-md-3">Upload Image</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="file" id="imagePath" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)" />
          <div [innerHTML]="uploadError" class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="blogDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description"
          required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter the blog body</label>
        <textarea formControlName="blogBodyHtml" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Author</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="blogAuthor" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Author name"
          required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select formControlName="blogCategory" class="form-control" id="category" required>
              <option *ngFor="let category of possibleCategories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
            </select>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!createBlogForm.form.valid">Post the blog</button>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Angular component

```
public createBlogForm: FormGroup;
  public imagePath: string;

  public blogTitle: string;
  public blogBodyHtml: string;
  public blogDescription: string;
  public blogCategory: string;
  public blogAuthor: string;
  public possibleCategories = ["Comedy", "Action", "Drama", "Technology","Cooking","Travel"];

  constructor(private blogpostService: BlogpostService, private toastr: ToastrManager, private router: Router,
    private _http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    console.log('CreateBlogComponent component constructor called');
   }
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("CreateBlogComponent onInIt called");

    this.createBlogForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      blogTitle: [''],
      blogDescription: [''],
      blogBodyHtml: [''],
      blogCategory: [''],
      blogAuthor: [''],
      imagePath:['']
    })

}

onSelectedFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  this.createBlogForm.get('imagePath').setValue(file)
}

public createBlog(): any {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('imagePath', this.createBlogForm.get('imagePath').value);
  formData.append('title', this.createBlogForm.get('blogTitle').value);
  formData.append('description', this.createBlogForm.get('blogDescription').value);
  formData.append('blogBody', this.createBlogForm.get('blogBodyHtml').value);
  formData.append('category', this.createBlogForm.get('blogCategory').value);
  formData.append('author', this.createBlogForm.get('blogAuthor').value);
 }

  this.blogpostService.createBlog(formData).subscribe(

    data => {

      this.toastr.successToastr('Blog Posted Susseccfully!', 'Success!');


    },

}
```

Comment: `[disabled]="!createBlogForm.form.valid"` should probably be `[disabled]="!createBlogForm.valid"`. And, `public blogTitle: string;` is declared, but never set to a value; initialize it to an empty string, or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your FormBuilder property hasn't initialized.

```
<div class="blog-form" *ngIf="createBlogForm">

</div>
```

Comment: It's now returning error createBlogForm.form is invalid

Answer (score 0):

The below code is referencing `blogTitle` property which isn't initialized.

```
  <div [hidden]="blogTitle.valid || blogTitle.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
       Blog Title is required 
  </div>
```

As it seems it tries to access a form control instead of property. For that you need to convert your `blogTitle` property in to this :

```
public get blogTitle() {
 return this.createBlogForm.get("blogTitle");
}
```